# List of assemblies in the .NET for Windows 8 profile

Tags: .net, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I am looking for the list of assemblies in the ".NET for Windows 8" profile. This is the profile used for WIndows 8 Metro-style applications, and like Silverlight doesn't use the full .NET framework.

Comment: Technically, it's called ".NET 4.5 Core" (or at least that's what Object Browser calls it).

Comment: That is what Krzysztof told me the offical name was when I asked him at Build.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[.NET for Metro style apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230232%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) — list of namespaces

[Converting your existing .NET Framework code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230302%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) — changes to the various APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any list currently... and WinRT is expected to change alot till the official release in 2012... current information about assemblies/not available in the "Metro/WinRT Client profile":

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2011/09/17/metro-net-framework-profile-windows-tailored.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The parts of the full profile that are available in the Metro-profile aren't delimited by some assemblies or namespaces. For example, the constructor `StremReader(Stream)` is present in the Metro-profile, but `StreamReader(string)` isn't.

Because of that, you would have to look [at the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230232.aspx) to find out what exactly is available and what isn't.