# Getting a Type Assembly in Windows 8

Tags: c#, mef, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm trying to use MEF in Windows 8.

In order to build up my `AssemblyCatalog` for the container, I need a reference to the assembly. In the past, I would have just done this:

```
var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(App).Assembly);
```

Mysteriously, the `Assembly` property no longer exists on the `Type` object. Anybody know of a good work around? Is there another way to get the assembly? I could load it using `Assembly.Load`, but I would need the name of the assembly. I can't get that from the type either.

Is using a `DirectoryCatalog` a possible alternate? I don't like the idea, but I'll do what I need to.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
using System.Reflection;
```

Use `type.GetTypeInfo().Assembly` instead.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467678/list-of-assemblies-in-the-net-for-windows-8-profile

Comment: Intellisense is not picking up GetTypeInfo() on typeof(App). Not sure what the deal is now.

Comment: Quote from documentation clears it up: "You can retrieve the TypeInfo object by calling the System.Reflection.IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(System.Type) method, which is an extension method for Type."

Comment: Works like a charm once I add `using System.Reflection;` so I can reference the extension function.

Comment: Actually, you found the answer before me :)

Comment: I'm using System.Reflection and tried the System.Reflection.IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(System.Type) but IntrospectionExtensions cannot be found?

Answer (score 6):

Found the answer after some digging through the loads of documentation on building metro style apps.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230302%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#reflection

The reflection aspects of the `Type` class have been moved to a new object called `System.Reflection.TypeInfo`. You can get an instance of this class by calling `type.GetTypeInfo()`.

So to get the Assembly: `typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly`.

Requires `using System.Reflection;`