# How to make this Reflection work with WinRT

Tags: c#, reflection

Reflection for Windows Store / WinRT applications is different than what I'm used to. How do I refactor this code block to work with WinRT?

*note: This block of code WORKS in a PCL that does not target Windows Store applications. (Profile104). As soon as I change the target to Profile158, it won't compile any longer.*

```
var migrationInterfaceType = typeof (IMigration);
var migrations =
    migrationInterfaceType.Assembly.GetTypes()
                          .Where(type => migrationInterfaceType.IsAssignableFrom(type) && !type.IsAbstract)
                          .OrderBy(type => type.Name);

// Cannot resolve symbol 'Assembly'
// Cannot resolve symbol 'IsAssignableFrom'
```

Essentially we have an interface called `IMigration`. Then we have an abstract class (`Migration`) that inherits IMigration. From there we create our migrations as follows.

```
public class Migration001 : Migration{

}

public class Migration002 : Migration{

}

// and so on.
```

What the code I'm struggling with needs to do is extract all of the Migrations into an IEnumerable<> so that I can loop over them and run them in order.  As I said before, the first code block works when it's not targeting WinRT, but now that it needs to, it won't compile due to

```
// Cannot resolve symbol 'Assembly'
// Cannot resolve symbol 'IsAssignableFrom'
```

I have attempted two different approaches, but both yield no results in the IEnumberable<>

**Failed attempt ONE**

```
var migrations =
    typeof(IMigration).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.DefinedTypes
                          .Where(type => type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(IMigration)) && !type.IsAbstract)
                          .OrderBy(type => type.Name);

// enumeration yielded no results
```

**Failed attempt TWO**

```
var migrationInterfaceType = typeof (IMigration);
var migrations = migrationInterfaceType.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.DefinedTypes
                          .Where(type => migrationInterfaceType.GetTypeInfo().IsSubclassOf(type.GetType()) && !type.IsAbstract)
                          .OrderBy(type => type.Name);

// enumeration yielded no results
```

And just in case you're wondering, here's how I'm running the migrations... nothing special.

```
foreach (var migration in migrations)
{
    Run(_serviceLocator.GetInstance<IMigration>(migration.Name));
}
```

Comment: What is the result of the failed attempts, and what would you expect? Did you do [research](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh535795(v=vs.110).aspx)? The error in your first comment (you _really_ should make the problem more clear) is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612186/getting-a-type-assembly-in-windows-8), the second will then probably disappear.

Comment: Yes I've been researching. The result is an empty `IEnumerable<>`. The first block of code WORKS when not required to target Windows Store apps.

Comment: The problem is you don't explain what that code is supposed to do. You only put two compiler errors in comments, and say it _"doesn't work properly with WinRT"_. You should know that is not an accurate problem description. I guess now that by _"**Failed attempt**"_ you mean _"returns an empty `IEnumerable<>`"_, but that also doesn't tell us what you expect it to return. It would _really_ help your question if you could give a little more info on what you're trying to do. I know enough of reflection to guess, and with that I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612186/).

Comment: We have the following classes. `public class Migration001 : Migration`, and the abstract class `public abstract class Migration : IMigration`. I expect it to return an `IEnumerable<IMigration>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trial and error lead to this. I do wish it was a little more clear :(

```
var currentAssembly = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
var migrations = currentAssembly.DefinedTypes
                                .Where( type => type.ImplementedInterfaces
                                                    .Any(inter => inter == typeof (IMigration)) && !type.IsAbstract )
                                .OrderBy( type => type.Name );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var migrations = typeof(IMigration).GetTypeInfo()
                                   .Assembly
                                   .DefinedTypes
                                   .Where(type => type.GetInterfaces()
                                                      .Any(itf=> 
                                         itf == typeof(IMigration)) && 
                                         !type.IsAbstract)
                                   .OrderBy(type => type.Name);
```

Comment: Unfortunately `GetInterfaces` doesn't work with WinRT. It needs to work with `IsSubclassOf`

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension method called GetTypeInfo to do that:

```
using System.Reflection;

.....

var migrationInterfaceType = typeof (Migration);
var migrations =
    migrationInterfaceType.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.ExportedTypes
                          .Where(type => migrationInterfaceType.GetTypeInfo().IsSubclassOf(type) && !type.IsAbstract)
                          .OrderBy(type => type.Name);
```